# This equality numerically looks well. Is there any justification?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

Is it true that

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2 \sum _{k=0}^n \left((k-1) \text{Li}_k\left(\frac{f(x)}{n^2}\right)-x \text{Li}_{k-1}\left(\frac{f(x)}{n^2}\right)\right)?$$

Here, $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function that I tested. I found this by chance, but numerically it looks OK (tried 5000 terms with $\exp$, $\cosh$, $\sinh$ and $\sin$). Is there any justification?

Comment: The use of $f(x)$ here is very strange...

Comment: @SamHopkins looks like this expansion works for arbitrary functions. Possibly, can be derived from the properties of polylogarithm.

Comment: Could you introduce your notation and use quantifiers? $f$ is not introduced, $x$ is not introduced.

Comment: @YCor this works for arbitrary function $f(x)$ that I tested.

Comment: Could it be a Riemann sum? The parenthesis can be rewritten by using $\Li_{k-1}(f(x)/n^2)=(f(x)/n^2) \frac{d \Li_k(f(x) /n^2)}{d f(x) /n^2}$

Comment: As mentioned in a comment that was for some reason deleted, can't you just replace $f(x)$ by $x$?

Comment: @Anixx Could you edit to make your question self-contained?

Comment: @SamHopkins yes

Comment: @YCor done.....

Comment: Since $f$ and $x$ are numbers that can be varied independently, the question really decomposes into two separate questions: The second term on the r.h.s. must sum to zero, the first term on the r.h.s. must sum to $f$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand\Li{\text{Li}}$This follows immediately because uniformly over all $k\ge-1$ we have $\Li_k(z)\sim z$ as $z\to0$, where $\Li_k$ is the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

---

**Details:** For $k\ge-1$ and $|z|\downarrow0$,
$$\Big|\frac{\Li_k(z)}z-1\Big|=\Big|\frac z{2^k}+\frac{z^2}{3^k}+\cdots\Big|\le|z|\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+2)|z|^j\to0$$
So, for $y:=f(x)$ and $n\to\infty$,
$$\Big|\sum_{k=0}^n x\Li_{k-1}(y/n^2)\Big|=O(|xy|(n+1)/n^2)\to0$$
and
$$2\sum_{k=0}^n (k-1)\Li_k(y/n^2)
=(1+o(1))\frac y{n^2}\,\sum_{k=0}^n 2(k-1)\to y.$$